# Mocking ODataQueryOptions on .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

Recently we decided to use the package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/7.0.0-beta1) for our solution in our services. The services have the ODataQueryOptions parameter and use it for filtering the data they provide.
To unit test this I need to Mock ODataQueryOptions somehow.
It used to be easier with System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions because you could create it with HttpRequestMessage as parameter but not any more.

I have this code

```
 public static ODataQueryOptions<T> Create<T>(string url = "", Action<ODataConventionModelBuilder> reconfigure = null)
               where T : class
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        serviceCollection.AddMvcCore().AddApplicationPart(typeof(ODataFactory).Assembly);

        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider());
        builder.EntitySet<T>("Entity");

        reconfigure?.Invoke(builder);

        ODataQueryContext context = new ODataQueryContext(builder.GetEdmModel(), typeof(T), new Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.ODataPath());

        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();

        var httpRequest = new DefaultHttpRequest(httpContext);

        // throws exception: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: provider
        return new ODataQueryOptions<T>(context, httpRequest);
    }
```

This code throws the next exception:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: provider
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions.HttpRequestExtensions.CreateRequestScope(HttpRequest request, String routeName)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions.HttpRequestExtensions.CreateRequestContainer(HttpRequest request, String routeName)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions.HttpRequestExtensions.GetRequestContainer(HttpRequest request)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions..ctor(ODataQueryContext context, HttpRequest request)
>      at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions`1..ctor(ODataQueryContext context, HttpRequest request)
>      at Services.Test.Internal.ODataFactory.Create[T](String url, Action`1 reconfigure) in C:\Users\wboun\source\repos\Services.Test\Internal\ODataFactory.cs:line 36

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured out how to get past the `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: provider` error and the `Cannot find the services container for the non-OData route.`

First off, when you create the DefaultHttpContext object, you have to set RequestServices to collection.BuildServiceProvider().

Next, you have to EnableDependencyInjection. I was able to do that by using Moq.

```
var routeBuilder = new RouteBuilder(Mock.Of<IApplicationBuilder>(x => x.ApplicationServices == provider));
routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
```

My full code is:

```
var collection = new ServiceCollection();

collection.AddOData();
collection.AddODataQueryFilter();
collection.AddTransient<ODataUriResolver>();
collection.AddTransient<ODataQueryValidator>();
collection.AddTransient<TopQueryValidator>();
collection.AddTransient<FilterQueryValidator>();
collection.AddTransient<SkipQueryValidator>();
collection.AddTransient<OrderByQueryValidator>();

var provider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();

var routeBuilder = new RouteBuilder(Mock.Of<IApplicationBuilder>(x => x.ApplicationServices == provider));
routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();

var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(provider);
modelBuilder.EntitySet<MyType>("MyType");
var model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();

var uri = new Uri("http://localhost/api/mytype/12345?$select=Id");

var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext{
    RequestServices = provider
};
HttpRequest req = new DefaultHttpRequest(httpContext)
{
    Method = "GET",
    Host = new HostString(uri.Host, uri.Port),
    Path = uri.LocalPath,
    QueryString = new QueryString(uri.Query)
};

var context = new ODataQueryContext(model, typeof(MyType), new Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.ODataPath());
var options = new ODataQueryOptions<MyType>(context, req);
```

Comment: I confirm that this has solved the issue and my test is now passing the point that wasn't before. Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm the same. This was my solution in .NET Core 3.1 using XUnit and Moq.

Answer (score 1):

After going trough the code for ODataQueryOptions we found the solution.

The main issue was missing initialization of needed objects in the service providers which is passed to the ODataConventionModelBuilder  constructor

```
ServiceProvider GetServiceProvider()
    {
        var collection = new ServiceCollection();

        collection.AddMvc();
        collection.AddOData();
        collection.AddTransient<ODataUriResolver>();
        collection.AddTransient<ODataQueryValidator>();
        collection.AddTransient<TopQueryValidator>();
        collection.AddTransient<FilterQueryValidator>();
        collection.AddTransient<SkipQueryValidator>();
        collection.AddTransient<OrderByQueryValidator>();

        return collection.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
```

Then the HttpRequest can be mocked with

```
 var uri = new Uri(url);

        HttpRequest request = new DefaultHttpRequest(http) {
            Method = "GET",
            Host = new HostString(uri.Host, uri.Port),
            Path = uri.LocalPath,
            QueryString = new QueryString(uri.Query)
        };
```

Comment: I run into exactly same problem and the more I search the less I find. Finally I found this post and tried your suggestion as you can see in the gist below but still it doesn't work and gives me the same error message. Any idea? https://gist.github.com/aboo/67230dae51189b08c0c39bb56a803d5f

Comment: If you could give me full exception stack would be nice. Also the environment. Because this happened to me for AspNetCore 2

Comment: Thanks @Mathean. I managed to fix that problem by using AddMvc instead of AddMvcCore. Now there is another issue, something about routing and it's asking me to enable dependency injection. But I can't find any solution for .net core to do that in unit test. Any hint is greatly appreciated. The exception -> https://gist.github.com/aboo/778293b942e38a05a464bbd3c5f08f26

Comment: Yeah I have searched for something and in IApplicationBuilder.UseMvc you have to put routes configuration where something like this is present: routes.Filter().EnableDependencyInjection();

Comment: I was able to get past the null provider issue by setting the RequestServices property in DefaultHttpContext to services.BuildServiceprovider(), but now I'm getting the error "Cannot find the services container for the non-OData route." This is normally resolved by calling routes.EnableDependencyInjection(), but I don't know how to set up routes in a unit test. Any ideas?

Comment: @mccow002 that's exactly the issue that we are discussing. I try to follow Mathean's lead and will update here if I was able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

According with @mccow002 answer, I just post the ODataHelper with the namespaces needed (because this gave me trouble too) that I have made for using it in Unit Tests that needs ODataQueryOptions for making them work:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query;
using Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Validators;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.OData.UriParser;
using Moq;
using System;

namespace Surgent.Evaluation.Tests.xUnit.Helpers
{
    public static class ODataHelper
    {
        public static ODataQueryOptions<T> Create<T>(string uri = "")
                where T : class
        {
            var provider = GetServiceProvider();
            var routeBuilder = new RouteBuilder(Mock.Of<IApplicationBuilder>(x => x.ApplicationServices == provider));
            routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();            

            var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(provider);
            modelBuilder.EntitySet<T>(nameof(T));
            var model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();

            var http = new DefaultHttpContext();
            var uri = new Uri(uri);

            http.Request.Method = "GET";
            http.Request.Host = new HostString(uri.Host, uri.Port);
            http.Request.Path = uri.LocalPath;
            http.Request.QueryString = new QueryString(uri.Query);
            http.RequestServices = provider;
                        
            HttpRequest request = http.Request;
            var context = new ODataQueryContext(model, typeof(T), new Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Routing.ODataPath());

            return new ODataQueryOptions<T>(context, request);
        }

        private static ServiceProvider GetServiceProvider()
        {
            var collection = new ServiceCollection();

            collection.AddMvcCore();
            collection.AddOData();
            collection.AddTransient<ODataUriResolver>();
            collection.AddTransient<ODataQueryValidator>();
            collection.AddTransient<TopQueryValidator>();
            collection.AddTransient<FilterQueryValidator>();
            collection.AddTransient<SkipQueryValidator>();
            collection.AddTransient<OrderByQueryValidator>();

            return collection.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is EnableDependencyInjection() in latest Microsoft.AspNet.OData 8.0.1?